# Find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $x^2\leq2^x$ for all $x\ge n$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, induction

Find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $x^2\leq2^x$ for all $x\ge n$. The idea here is to prove the inequality via induction for every $x$ greater than this $n$. I know how to prove it via induction, what I can't find is this minimum $n$.

Comment: The solution is $n=1$

Comment: Yes, I want to know FROM which number this inequality is satisfied, I know it doesn't hold for 3 but for every x greater than or equal to 4 it is valid. What I'm not able to prove is why it must be greater than or equal to 4

Comment: Take the $\log$...

Comment: @Mathtask You don't have to prove that it doesn't hold for any lower numbers other than three. In other words, you can show that it fails for $3$, works for $4$, and then induce starting from $4$. If it fails for $3$, then $n > 3$.

Answer (score 1):

You can just try small values of $n$ to find that $3$ is the only $n$ that fails.  You can then do your induction starting at $4$ and be done.

It might be interesting to look carefully at the small terms to see why the induction would fail if you tried to start lower, at $1$ or $2$.  Your induction relies on the fact that for $n \ge 4, \left(\frac {n+1}n\right)^2 \le 2$ so the left side of the inequality is multiplied by a smaller number than the right when passing from $n$ to $n+1$.  This fails when $n$ is small.

Comment: Got it, I did the little tests, but I wanted a general way to show this

Comment: You said you knew how to prove it by induction.  Note that $\frac {n+1}n$ is decreasing with $n$ and (\frac 54)^2 \lt 2$

Comment: yes, but how would I know by induction the error for x=3. if we state par x greater than or equal to 1. where would the error be?

Comment: Because $(\frac32)^2\gt 2$.  That is why I said it was interesting to look at why it fails.

Comment: where did you get that ( n+1/n)^2 <= 2?

Comment: Think about it.  That is the key step in the induction.

Comment: yes yes, is that I would like to find a way to show this failure without trial and error

Comment: You can if you just look at the value of $\frac {n+1}n$ for various values of $n$.  When would its square be greater than $2$?